# linker command error while integrating google drive API

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I am working on integrating Google Drive integration in my app. And I've added `GTL.Framework` but it give me an error of "**linker command error with exit code 1**". I've tried adding these keys "**-ObjC , -all_load**" in other linker flag in Build settings but not worked.

Please help if any body know what kind of thing I missing here.

Comment: Have check your project Architecture and framework Architecture. It may be valid architecture issue like 64 bit.

Comment: I have checked, this is not the problem. thanks for reply

Answer (score 0):

That can happen if the same .m file is referenced multiple times in your target's "Compile Sources" section in "Build Phases". Remove duplicate entries and you should be fine. 
OR
Accidentally importing the .m file instead of the .h file. Check for the same.